# How to extract multiple layouts?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

In Blender I looked for ways to extract the layout of all objects at once but I could not. The best I could do was to put together all the objects and extract a single layout.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you get some screenshots or mockups of what you mean here?

Comment: I have 45 individual objects and I need to export each object of this layout (UV Map). Is it possible to export only one layout at a time?